# DD4t 2.0 Java: How to get BaseViewModel populated for Dynamic Components

Tags: dd4t, java

I am calling ComponentPresentationFactory.getComponentPresentation(componentURI, templateURI) method to retrieve a dynamic component in my Page Controller. The Component Presentation object returned by this method has the ComponentImpl, ComponentTemplateImpl and other fields set on it, but not the ViewModel.

I used the following TBB's in my dynamic component template in Tridion

- Generate dynamic component presentation
- Add inherited metadata to component
- Publish binaries for component

My view model class extends TridionViewModelbase and has the annotation

```
@ViewModel (
        rootElementNames = {"article"},
        setComponentObject = true)
```

where "article" is the Root Element Name of the component schema.

When I use the component as embedded on the page (with non-dynamic template), I get the ViewModel on the Component Presentation object (In this case my Page Controller calls pageFactory.findPageByUrl method).

Now for my view I use Thymeleaf and so I am not using any jsp tags. I am on dd4t2.0.2

What am I missing here for retrieving dynamic component? Am I calling the correct API? Is there any example for dynamic component in java?

**Update after comment**

I retrieve the view models from the component presentation in my controller and create a list of them which I then set on the request (Spring frameworks view model). In my Thymeleaf view I iterate over the list and display the fragment related to the view models name. So in the controller I have something like…

```
Page pageModel = pageFactory.findPageByUrl(url, publicationResolver.getPublicationId());
List<ComponentPresentationModel> cpModelList = new ArrayList<ComponentPresentationModel>();
for (ComponentPresentation cp : pageModel.getComponentPresentations())
{
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cp.getAllViewModels()))
    {
        for (String key : cp.getAllViewModels().keySet())
        {
            BaseViewModel viewModel = cp.getViewModel(key);
            String name = String.format("%s-%s", RenderUtils.fixUrl(RenderUtils.getViewName(cp)), key);
            ComponentPresentationModel cpModel = new ComponentPresentationModel(name, viewModel);
            cpModelList.add(cpModel);
        }
    }
}
```

In Thymeleaf view …

```
<div th:each="cp,cpIndex : ${componentPresentationModel}">
  <th:block th:switch="${cp.name}">
    <th:block th:case="'generic-content-Content'">
      <div th:replace="components/generic-content :: Content(component=${cp.model})"></div>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:case="'article-component-template-Article'">
      <div th:replace="components/article-component-template :: Article(component=${cp.model})"></div>
    </th:block>
  </th:block>
</div>
```

Comment: How are the models now read in the Thymeleaf resolver? By using Beans on the request stack?

Comment: I retrieve the view models from the component presentation in my controller and create a list of them which I then set on the request (Spring frameworks view model). In my Thymeleaf view I iterate over the list and display the fragment related to the view models name. Updated the question with more details on how its done.

Comment: I see it's already fixed - great!

Answer (score 1):

DD4T 2.0.4 has fix for this (Issue #38)

I updated to 2.0.4 and now I get the ViewModel populated for dynamic components.